# Redirecs with /bin/bash from Java Runtime exec()

Tags: java, linux, bash, runtime.exec

I'm trying to use a redirect in a command executed with the `exec()`-method of `java.lang.Runtime` on Ubuntu 14.04

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String command = "echo bla > bla.txt";
    System.out.println("Command : " + command);
    Process process = runtime.exec(command);
    printLines(" stdout", process.getInputStream());
    printLines("  error", process.getErrorStream());
    process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("ExitValue : " + process.exitValue());
}

private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    try(Stream<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins)).lines()) {
        lines.forEach(line -> System.out.println(name + " : " + line));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Command : echo bla > bla.txt
 stdout : bla > bla.txt
ExitValue : 0
```

So `bla > bla.txt` is written to `stdout` but of course there is no redirect to `bla.txt`.

Perhapes shell redirects are not possible in a simple `exec()`.

So I tried to change the `command = "/bin/bash -c 'echo bla > bla.txt'"` to use the whole echo and redirect as a parameter to `/bin/bash`.

With this I get the result:

```
Command : /bin/bash -c 'echo bla > bla.txt'
  error : bla: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
  error : bla: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ExitValue : 1
```

Of course `/bin/bash -c 'echo bla > bla.txt'`works fine on Ubuntu and creates the desired file.

I found no place where I could set the single quotes to get a satisfying result, and I also tried with all kinds of escape characters to escape the spaces or the redirect (`>`).

It works if I use a command array like

```
String cmdArray[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "echo bla > bla.txt"};
Process process = runtime.exec(cmdArray);
```

, but it has to be a single string because the entire command has to be build somewhere else.

I surely know

- that there are better ways to write strings to files,
- that it may be a bad idea to execute commands build somewhere else,
- and so on ...

I'm just curious why this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that exec uses simple StringTokenizer with any white space as a delimiter to parse the actual command. Therefore it's portable as it does work nowhere when you pass something complex :-)

The workaround you chose is correct way, portable and most of all safest asyou ddon't need to escape if the command contained for example quotes etc.

Comment: Seems to be right. `"/bin/bash" "-c" "'echo" "bla" ">" "bla.txt'"` - single tokens -  gives the same result on the commandline. What a pity.

Answer (score 1):

```
String command = "echo bla > bla.txt";
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
```

The `> blah.txt` text in your command is shell syntax to redirect standard output. It's implemented by shells like `sh` or `bash`.

`Runtime.exec()` doesn't use a shell to run commands. The way it launches commands is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)). Basically, it uses its own logic to split the command string into arguments at spaces, then directly executes the resulting command.

If you want to invoke a command which should be interpreted as a shell command, you need to explicitly invoke a shell:

```
String[] command = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo bla > bla.txt" };
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
```

Comment: That's why I tried to call `/bin/bash` with the original command and redirect as parameter. Yoour answer was already part of my question.

Comment: It seems to me the point of your question was why the other solutions don't work. That's the question that I answered. As you agree, providing the arguments as a list does work; you just have an architectural reason why you can't do it that way.

Comment: I was to lazy to follow the links. I wandered why `exec("/bin/bash -c 'echo bla > bla.txt'")` does not work and the part about `StringTokenizer` following the first link gives the explanation. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: how can we get output with the String[] method? I was using `while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)` but that no longer works

Comment: @MikePalmice If you're having trouble, you should ask a new question and include the code that's not working for you. See [ask].